# Geographical information management with GAE datastore and objectify

Tags: gwt, google-cloud-datastore, geocoding, objectify, gwt-platform

I am doing a website about places to visit using java, gwt, gae, gwt-platform and objectify for the datastore and GWT maps V3 [github.com/twistedpair/GWT-Maps-V3-Api]. (I don't know if is the best solution but for now im advancing, slowly but ok :))

Question:
What you think can be the best approach to store latitude and longitude of a place being able later to search places near it?

I was trying the approach to save the longitude and latitude into strings using lexicographical order using
http://code.google.com/p/sappenin/source/browse/trunk/SappeninUtils/src/main/java/com/sappenin/util/BigDecimalStringCodec.java?r=146
But I didn't achieve to get it working and as I understand, I would have to query first by latitude and then by longitude and I think it wont be practical at all.

I don't know if is better to use GeoPt in my entities or only the values latitude and longitude as two strings or long (as bigdecimal is not supported). I think will be more or less the same because internally GeoPt is the same, two numbers.

I think the best approach will be geomodel but is in python then I started to check http://code.google.com/p/javageomodel/
But I couldn't manage, the problem is that geomodel is not for objectify. I found an approach of javageomodel for objectify but seems quite old. 
[github.com/bfuster/javageomodel]
I would try to take the original javageomodel and try to modify it but I wanted to know if someone knows a better way to do this.

Which option you recommend? Maybe there is a very easy way to do it now in 2012 but I couldn't find it and I'm rounding around one week through Google.

Thank you in advance for your opinion!

I hope the question is more or less clear because as you can see, I have a huge mess in my mind right now, ;)

Comment: just an advice, if you plan to release a hobby application hosted for free on GAE, take care about quotas. datastore read operations on gwt appli using google maps can make your app in quota exceed in a very short time even with almost nobody :-(

Comment: Thank you for the advise!, yes, I saw already that things are growing fast and even is not working the website. For now is the final project of the university and I already said I will use this technologies but if it works somehow, I will have to make quite a lot of changes to try to spend as few as I can and also to pay less.

Comment: I get this problem, quotas were reached with only bots activity ! So I rewrited GAE things to tomcat/mysql stuff, now, the app is hosted at home :-)

Comment: You should make the GWT clients do the geo queries if possible, so it does not add up to your quota.

Comment: I'm trying it, I can make geocode queries or google maps queries by the client, but still I will have to query my datastore to fetch the nearest places, :s, We will see how it goes, ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example of how to use geohashing with GAE and Objectify here:

https://github.com/stickfigure/motomapia

The demo is here:

http://www.motomapia.com/

The geohash library is here:

http://code.google.com/p/javageomodel/

Comment: Hi, thx!, I had downloaded also this project and I was taking a look couple of days ago but as I understand it, in it, the query to the places by geolocation (In wikimapia.java -> box()) is made to the api of wikimapia and inside of the motomapia is being searching later by Id in Places.java ->syncplaces(), not by lat and lng that is what i'm trying. This is what I understood from code, I'm not sure if I miss something, :)

Comment: Look at the code in DownloadServlet which fetches all the places in a bounded area to generate the POI file.

Comment: I will take a look there, looks nice!, Thx a lot!

Comment: Hi, this post is several years old now so wanted to check in if this is still relevant or if there are newer examples/samples you would recommend. Just looking to store lat/long in an entity and then later be able to query all such entities with in X radius of a location. Thank you for the constant help!

Comment: Take a look at the Search API, which has some geo facilities in it. The datastore also has some native ability to handle geo queries, but this never made it into public general availability (or simply hasn't yet).

Comment: @stickfigure I'm trying to stay away from the Search API and work with just objectify/datastore... I took at a look at it but foresee technical/financial problems down the line with incorporating it into my application. From my research GeoHashing looks like the way to go (Firebase uses GeoHashing too), but I can't seem to find a good example of it for objectify/datastore. I looked at your answer but it says the geohash library is deprecated..? Do you have any advice on where I should look to find a good GeoHashing + Datastore/objectify example? Is motomapia still the best? Thanks!

Comment: Or should I just ask a new question on StackOverflow?

Comment: Honestly, I would just get used to the Search API, which is production-ready today. There are a lot of types of queries that the datastore is a poor fit for. It's usually pretty easy to sync a subset of data to a specialized index that lets you satisfy the more exotic queries. I've found the Search API to be very helpful.

You can ask Google about getting access to the geo index facility builtin to the datastore (they were advertising for alpha testers on the google group some time ago) but it's been very quiet for quite a while.

Comment: @stickfigure Thank you for your advice. After more research, you have swayed me to use the Search API. If Google does release datastore geo queries then I should be able to easily make the switch then.

Comment: You can make the search API a lot more palatable by wrapping it in a more human-friendly interface. The builder patterns they use in the public API are kinda tedious. Aside from the API itself, the Search facility is pretty awesome and the index ends up being a tiny fraction of the size of what would have to be stored in the datastore as indexes.